# How to make led fade out in 5s using PWM in arduino

Tags: arduino

How to make a led fade out in 5s using PWM in arduino. I wrote this function, it didn't work. I try to call this function.

```
const int minPWM = 0;
const int maxPWM = 255;
int fadeValue = 255;
int fadeIncrement = 5;
unsigned long previousFadeMillis;
int fadeInterval = 50;

void setLightPWM(unsigned long thisMillis) {

  if (thisMillis - previousFadeMillis >= fadeInterval) {

 fadeValue = fadeValue - fadeIncrement;
 if (fadeValue <= minPWM) {
   // At min, limit and change direction
   fadeValue = minPWM;
 }


   analogWrite(garageLED, fadeValue);


  previousFadeMillis = thisMillis;
}
   return;
}
```

Also, I wrote this line in loop()

```
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  setLightPWM(currentMillis);
```

Comment: it only worked the first time, then the led didn't fade out.

Comment: I think some "reset" code should be needed. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Really need to see the code that calls this function in its complete form. If you have both of those in your loop then it's very unlikely `currentMillis` will ever increase.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean initFade;
long startTime;

void setup(){
  startTime=0;
  initFade=false;
}

void loop(){
  if(initFade){
    startTime = millis();
    initFade=false;
  }
  initFade = customizedFade;
}

boolean customizedFade(long fadeTime){
  long timePassed = millis()-startTime;
  if(timePassed < fadeTime ){
    analogWrite(LEDPIN, map(timePassed,0,5000,255,0));
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that this code is complete (along with a `pinMode(garageLED, OUTPUT)` call and the definition of `garageLED`), and that the idea is to make an LED fade in and out (as you wrote in a comment "at min [...] change direction".

If my assumptions are right, then your code is missing the ability to invert the fade change. When it goes below the minimum it is set to the minimum value, but then nothing happens. At each further call it is set again to the minimum value.

So if the idea was to fade in and out you need to change the "fading direction":

```
if (fadeValue <= minPWM) {
    // At min, limit and change direction
    fadeValue = minPWM;
    fadeIncrement = - fadeIncrement;   //<-- Invert the value of "fadeIncrement"
}
```

and then the same thing when hitting the maximum value:

```
if (fadeValue >= maxPWM) {
    // At max, limit and change direction
    fadeValue = maxPWM;
    fadeIncrement = - fadeIncrement;   //<-- Invert the value of "fadeIncrement"
}
```

If the idea is to fade out, then suddenly fully turn on and fade out again, then you only need to set to *maximum* value when hitting the minimum:

```
if (fadeValue <= minPWM) {
    // At min, limit and change direction
    fadeValue = maxPWM;
}
```

Here is a working sketch whit your code plus some extra lines and my changes. All what I added or modified is marked with a `// <--` symbol.

```cpp
const int garageLED = 5;             // <-- added to make the sketch work

const int minPWM = 0;
const int maxPWM = 255;
int fadeValue = 255;
int fadeIncrement = 1;                // <-- why not use the smallest increment value?
unsigned long previousFadeMillis;
int fadeInterval = 20;                // <-- 20ms interval to get a 5s fade time with (fadeIncrement == 1)
                                      //     (fadeInterval = fadeTime/fadeSteps), where fadeTime = 5000 ms
                                      //     and fadeSteps = (maxPWM - minPWM)/fadeIncrement.
                                      //     So in this case fadeInterval = 5000/((255 - 0)/1) = 5000/255 =~ 19,6

void setLightPWM(unsigned long thisMillis) {

  if (thisMillis - previousFadeMillis >= fadeInterval) {

    fadeValue = fadeValue - fadeIncrement;

    if (fadeValue <= minPWM) {
      // At min, limit and change direction
      fadeValue = minPWM;
      fadeIncrement = - fadeIncrement;   //<-- Invert the value of "fadeIncrement"
    }

    if (fadeValue >= maxPWM) {           //<-- Added if block
      // At max, limit and change direction
      fadeValue = maxPWM;
      fadeIncrement = - fadeIncrement;   //<-- Invert the value of "fadeIncrement"
    }


    analogWrite(garageLED, fadeValue);


    previousFadeMillis = thisMillis;
  }

  return;
}



void setup() {                              // <-- added to make the sketch work
  pinMode(garageLED, OUTPUT);               // <--
}                                           // <--


void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  setLightPWM(currentMillis);
}
```